# Are servers like apache2 offline by default?

Tags: server, apache2

Meaning they can only be accessed from localhost, and not from a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apache can be accessed from any other machine. You just need the IP address of your computer to see your apache server on any computer in the network with that IP address. For example, if your computer IP is 192.168.0.101, you can access apache from the same network with:

```
http://192.168.0.101
```

To access your apache server from the WAN, you need a static IP/domain. You can create one for free to test at http://www.mydns.com/.